# Setting the focuspolicy of differents class of widgets

Tags: pyqt5, python-3.8

I am currently learning PyQt concepts. Through easy examples, I am trying to play with the tab key to jump from one widget to another.

I manage to disable the focus policy on a PushButton, making it impossible to get the focus on it while pushing Tab. However, with a DialogButton, I do not manage to do so.

I feel managing this policy is possible with every type of widget, but I feel a bit lost with all their specificities.

Here is my current code :

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui
import sys

class TabWidget(QtWidgets.QDialog): # class to implement dialog box
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setWindowTitle("Tab Widget App")

        tabWidget = QtWidgets.QTabWidget() # creation of the tab widget object
        tabWidget.addTab(FirstTab(), "First Tab") # fill with first widget
        tabWidget.addTab(SecondTab(), "Second Tab")
        tabWidget.addTab(ThirdTab(), "Third Tab")

        self.buttonbox = QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox(QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox.Ok | QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox.Cancel)
        self.buttonbox.setFocusPolicy(QtCore.Qt.NoFocus)
        self.buttonbox.accepted.connect(self.accept)
        self.buttonbox.rejected.connect(self.reject)
                    
        tabWidget.addTab(FourthTab(), "Fourth Tab")            
        vbox_layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        vbox_layout.addWidget(tabWidget)
        vbox_layout.addWidget(self.buttonbox)
        self.setLayout(vbox_layout)

    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        print(event.key())


class FirstTab(QtWidgets.QWidget): # class to implement simple widget
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        name = QtWidgets.QLabel("Name:")
        nameEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()

        dob = QtWidgets.QLabel("Birth Date:")
        dobEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()

        age = QtWidgets.QLabel("Age:")
        ageEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()

        phone = QtWidgets.QLabel("Phone:")
        phoneEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()

        vbox_layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        vbox_layout.addWidget(name)
        vbox_layout.addWidget(nameEdit)
        vbox_layout.addWidget(dob)
        vbox_layout.addWidget(dobEdit)
        vbox_layout.addWidget(age)
        vbox_layout.addWidget(ageEdit)
        vbox_layout.addWidget(phone)
        vbox_layout.addWidget(phoneEdit)
        self.setLayout(vbox_layout)
        
class SecondTab(QtWidgets.QWidget): # class to implement simple widget
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        selectGroup = QtWidgets.QGroupBox("Select Operating Systems")
        combo = QtWidgets.QComboBox()
        list = {"Windows", "Mac", "Linux"}
        combo.addItems(list)

        selectLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        selectLayout.addWidget(combo)
        selectGroup.setLayout(selectLayout)

        checkGroup = QtWidgets.QGroupBox("Which Operation System Do You Like?")
        windows = QtWidgets.QCheckBox("Windows")
        mac = QtWidgets.QCheckBox("Mac")
        linux = QtWidgets.QCheckBox("Linux")

        checklayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        checklayout.addWidget(windows)
        checklayout.addWidget(mac)
        checklayout.addWidget(linux)
        checkGroup.setLayout(checklayout)

        mainlayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        mainlayout.addWidget(selectGroup)
        mainlayout.addWidget(checkGroup)
        self.setLayout(mainlayout)

class ThirdTab(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        label = QtWidgets.QLabel("Terms And Conditions")
        listwidget = QtWidgets.QListWidget()
        list = []
        
        for i in range(1,20):
            list.append("This Is Terms And Conditions")

        listwidget.insertItems(0, list)

        checkbox = QtWidgets.QCheckBox("Agree The Terms And Condition")

        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(label)
        layout.addWidget(listwidget)
        layout.addWidget(checkbox)
        self.setLayout(layout)

class FourthTab(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.groupBox = QtWidgets.QGroupBox("Issue", objectName = 'groupBox')

        self.grid_layout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.groupBox)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)

        self.widgetOne = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.groupBox, tabChangesFocus = True)
        self.widgetOne_label = QtWidgets.QLabel("widgetOne")
        self.widgetOne.setObjectName("WidgetOne")
        self.grid_layout.addWidget(self.widgetOne, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        self.grid_layout.addWidget(self.widgetOne_label, 0, 0, 1, 1)

        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.widgetOne.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.grid_layout.addWidget

        self.widgetTwo = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.groupBox, tabChangesFocus = True)
        self.widgetTwo_label =  QtWidgets.QLabel("widgetTwo")
        self.widgetTwo.setObjectName("widgetTwo")
        self.grid_layout.addWidget(self.widgetTwo, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        self.grid_layout.addWidget(self.widgetTwo_label, 0, 1, 1, 1)
        
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.widgetTwo.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.grid_layout.addWidget

        self.widgetThree = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.groupBox, tabChangesFocus = True)
        self.widgetThree_label =  QtWidgets.QLabel("widgetThree")
        self.widgetThree.setObjectName("widgetThree")
        self.grid_layout.addWidget(self.widgetThree, 4, 0, 1, 1)
        self.grid_layout.addWidget(self.widgetThree_label, 3, 0, 1, 1)

        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.widgetThree.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.grid_layout.addWidget

        self.widgetFour = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.groupBox, tabChangesFocus = True)
        self.widgetFour_label =  QtWidgets.QLabel("widgetFour")
        self.widgetFour.setObjectName("WidgetFour")
        self.grid_layout.addWidget(self.widgetFour, 4, 1, 1, 1)
        self.grid_layout.addWidget(self.widgetFour_label, 3, 1, 1, 1)

        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.widgetFour.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.grid_layout.addWidget

        v_layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        v_layout.addWidget(self.groupBox)
        self.setLayout(v_layout)

        self.setTabOrder(self.widgetOne, self.widgetTwo)
        self.setTabOrder(self.widgetTwo, self.widgetThree)
        self.setTabOrder(self.widgetThree, self.widgetFour)
        self.setTabOrder(self.widgetFour, self.widgetOne)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    tabwidget = TabWidget()
    tabwidget.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

The involved button is my "buttonbox" of type QDialogButton. I have set the focus policy to NoFocus. But when I launch the script and use the tab key in FourthTab, the focus still goes on OK / Cancel.

Are there some restrictions about this option? Or is there something I am missing?

Comment: For future reference, please try to keep your examples as *minimal* as possible (read how to create a [mre] if you didn't yet). Almost 80% of your code (all the tab classes) is completely unnecessary and distracting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The focus policy is not propagated to the children.

When you set the focus policy on the button box, its children (the buttons) still have their default policy (which is `StrongFocus`).

If you want to disable that for all buttons, you need to do it explicitly, for instance:

```
self.buttonbox.button(self.buttonbox.Ok).setFocusPolicy(QtCore.Qt.NoFocus)
```

Or, for any button:

```
    for button in self.buttonbox.findChildren(QtWidgets.QAbstractButton):
        button.setFocusPolicy(QtCore.Qt.NoFocus)
```

<sup>Note that the `keyPressEvent` is only received by a parent if none of its children has handled it, so if you're trying to capture the <kbd>Tab</kbd> you need to install an event filter on the whole QApplication instead, otherwise it's still possible that some widget will capture and accept it, thus preventing you to receive it.</sup>

Comment: I tried with both solutions and it worked fine. It even helped me to fix other similar issues with other widgets. Thank you for the precisions.